# Wallpaper Clock Screenlet not working in 12.04

Tags: desktop-background, screenlets

I spent all morning making a wallpaper clock in `GIMP`, I downloaded [screenlets](http://www.screenlets.org) from the software centre, then downloaded and installed the [Wallpaper Clock](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=66717) screenlet and installed my wallpaper successfully, only to find wallpaper clocks don't work in 12.04.

Is there any particular reason for this? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/use-wallpaper-clocks-live-earth.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.